# Why is timeit slower when called from a python file with map and a predefined function over being called via cli with map and a lambda expression?

Tags: python

I am checking whether lambda expressions are faster compared to predefined functions. Here is my code to test predefined function

```
import timeit


def ad(x):
    return x + 2


def test():
    xs = range(10)
    map(ad, xs)

print timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import ad, test")
```

Running it

```
python add.py
3.21725106239
```

Changed it to a lambda expression as follows

```
import timeit


def test():
    xs = range(10)
    map(lambda x: x+2, xs)

print timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test")
```

The speed is more or less the same, that is ~3 sec+.

However when I run from the command line the following code the results are as follows

```
➜  /tmp python -mtimeit -s'xs=range(10)' 'map(lambda x: x+2, xs)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.42 usec per loop
```

That is nearly a second lower.

Comment: The later in in micro-seconds! i.e. ~1000000x faster. I imagine it is related to the way you call your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your commandline version, you're creating the `xs` list in your setup code, so it's creation is not getting timed.  In the non-commandline version, `xs` is created within `test` which is the function being timed.  Because of this, the two versions aren't timing the same thing.

- **Commandline**: Timing only `map(...)`
- **File**: Timing `list(10)` and `map(...)`